# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Finger

Tags: java, android

I´am trying to use this [Finger.java](http://elm.eeng.dcu.ie/~ee402/ee402notes/html/java/Finger.java) for my Android project,
But I get this error.

```
$java Finger username@host.com
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Finger
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Finger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Finger. Program will exit.
```

I have looked on Google
and then I try this:

```
java -classpath .finger
```

And...

```
set classpath=%classpath%:.Finger.java:
```

But this does not work :(

I get the Java file from this page: http://elm.eeng.dcu.ie/~ee402/ee402notes/html/ch10s03.html#FingerScreenGrab

I only need to call it from my 'mainActivity' for my project.

My Java setup is like this:

```
$java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

and

```
$javac -version
javac 1.7.0_07
```

Comment: hmm I have not compiled it... do I need to do this if I only need to call the methods from my 'mainActivity'? can I not just write 'import Finger;'?

Comment: To people considering voting to close this question: *This question should probably **not be closed as off-topic**, since it appears to fundamentally come down to what the `java` and `javac` commands do, how to use them, and what kinds of files they can be used on. Those are not really programming questions. This appears to be a question on how to **use the Java software in Ubuntu**, rather than how to write Java code, so it would be considered on-topic for our site.*

Comment: Ok sorry if this is too easy for this site. I have make a lot of java-code but I use Eclipse, I has never needed to think about compiled commands before now. The reason I try two run it in the terminal is to secure me that class work. The Finger.java file is an simple-program so I will my change it to return the output-data as string(but this is not an part of my question).. Ok now I have try compiled 'javac Finger.java' so the compiled-file is 'Finger.class'. Then I get this error(http://paste.ubuntu.com/1182163/) look it up, and I only need to changes the JRE to openJDK-7 and then it runs:)

Comment: I'm glad the problem is solved. I've posted an answer detailing the solution for the first problem (which is what you posted the question about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As discussed in comments...*

`Finger.java` is a Java source code file. `.java` source code files cannot be run in that form; they must first be compiled.

As you've explained, `Finger.java` is intended to provide code that may be used as *part of* a Java program, and *also* is designed to function as a standalone application.

To use a class defined in a `.java` file in another program, it will have to be compiled, but this often need not be a *separate* build step from building your whole program. Typically, when you build your program, all the `.java` files in its source code are compiled. Integrated development environments like Eclipse ensures this happens, but you can do this from the command-line as well.

*How* you'll do it depends on whether or not you're using an automated build system (such as [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) or [SCons](http://www.scons.org/)). If you're not using an automated build system, you can still often build from the command-line with a single invocation of the `javac` command; the manpage for your `javac` implementation details how (run `man javac`). Since this is not the focus of your question, I won't go into any more detail here about how to build a Java application from multiple source code files.

Since any `.java` source code file **will need to be compiled before it can be run**, and you want to run `Finger` as a standalone program, you will have to first compile it:

```
javac Finger.java
```

Then you can run it:

```
java Finger
```

That's actually running the file called `Finger.class` that is created from compiling `Finger.java` with `javac` as detailed above. The `java` command cannot execute Java source code.